# Multiple AJAX URL request at once dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, django-rest-framework

Greeting, I have a datatable in my html and when clicked on the table rows it will get the id of the row and send an ajax request to my REST API for either update or delete the selected row, its working but if I try to select and update or delete multiple row at once, let say row 1, 4 and 6 it will throw and url error e.g:

error : `PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/1,4,6/ 404 (Not Found)`

On request How can I split the url individually?
eg :

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/1
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/4
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/6
```

Below is my AJAX code, any help is much appreciated TQVM

```
        idSrc: 'id',
        ajax: {
            edit: {
                type: 'PUT',
                url: '/dashboard/content_detail/_id_/',
                data: function (content_data) {
                    var updated_data = {};
                    $.each(content_data.data, function (id, value) {
                        updated_data['search_type'] = searchid;
                        updated_data['project'] = projectid;
                        updated_data['description'] = value['description'];
                        updated_data['category'] = value['category'];
                        updated_data['name'] = value['name'];
                    });
                    return updated_data;
                },

                success: function () {
                    content_table.api().ajax.reload();
                }
            },
            remove: {
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: '/dashboard/content_detail/_id_/',
                data: function (content_data) {
                    var deleted_data = {};
                    $.each(content_data.data, function (id, value) {
                        deleted_data['id'] = id;
                    });
                    return deleted_data;
                },
                success: function () {
                    content_table.api().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PUT request consider `1,4,6` as string `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/content_detail/1,4,6` rather than numbers.

On server side convert string to character array, convert those array element to numbers and you will get array of numbers, use that array to update database

Comment: thank you for your input, unfortunately my I'm still an amateur programmer. can you provide me with the example steps. thanks

Comment: As I'm front end developer I can give you logic for server side, its not possible for me to write steps for server side.
Are you working on server side?

Comment: Yes I am, I'm actually having the same issue as you are, I know what should but I dont know how to do it

Comment: Please ask to your sever side programmer and suggest him the logic provided above. Hope he will find it easy.